# How to get daily percentage of users for the past 7 days in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get the past 7days numbers of users with the daily percentage , especially the last day...

```
$dailyUsers = User::selectRaw('DATE(created_at) as date, COUNT(*) as count')
->groupBy('date')
->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subWeek())
 ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the user count

```
$user_count = User::count();
```

Then get difference (increase) between the two numbers like:

```
$diff = $user_count-$dailyUsers->count;
$percent = $diff/$user_count*100;
```

This should work hope so...